# How to use Finverse in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

When using **finverse** code in **matlab** there might not be a unique answer for that, how can we use if to choose one of these?

Comment: have you tried to search it on internet first??

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation of finverse](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/finverse.html) which can of course be found using `doc finverse`.

It is mentioned that there will be no warning if the inverse is not unique, and it is not mentioned which one is chosen in that case. Hence I think it is safe to assume that you cannot instruct matlab on which inverse to choose.

If that is really required, you will probably not be able to use the standard implementation.